# Variable is not updating data React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, asynchronous, components

I have in my App.jsx a fetch to the backend to request the user data and then in a child component I use that info to show or not something (depending if we have user or not). With the React Dev Tools extension for Chrome, I can see that the variable has information, but I don't understand why my code is not working.

```
const [myEvents, setMyEvents] = useState(null)

const eventsFetch = async () => {

    // I use this conditional to wait until the backend response.
    if(user == null) {
        console.log('test')
        setTimeout(eventsFetch, 250)
    } else {
        const resEvents = await getAllEventsUser(user._id);
        setMyEvents(resEvents);
        
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    setMenuHome(true);
    eventsFetch();
}, []);
```

The conditional is always going where the console.log is.

Comment: add sample in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: add myEvents as dependency in useEffect, the current useEffect will trigger only once, change the code to 

  useEffect(() => {
        setMenuHome(true);
        eventsFetch();
    }, [myEvents]);

Comment: @A.R.SEIF https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-sea-y79u9 there is the code. I should say if for example i refresh the website in the index, and then i go to the profile, everything is working fine. But if I refresh the websithe directly in the profile endpoint is not.

Comment: @RahulPal I tried adding myEvents as a dependecy in useEffect, but is still not working.

Comment: hello error in sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the variable user to the useEffect dependecy and now it's working